# Image content printed on screen after inserting wordpress attachment programatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm inserting attachment for a post like this programatically:

```
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($gallery);

$attachment = array(
    'guid' => '', 
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($gallery)),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $gallery, $post_id );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $gallery ); 
$update_data = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Everything is working fine and attachment is added correctly but I get image code displayed on my page. :S

Something like this(I'm not going to post the whole code):

```
����JFIF``��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 90 ��C     ��C         ����"��    ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B����    #3R�br� $4�
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: In what way is that base64?

Comment: That looks like more like compression than base64 encoding...

Comment: The _"weird base64 code"_ you mention *is* the image. How do you fetch this image? It seems like it is missing a Content-Type http header.

Comment: Yeah my wrong, it is the image. But it should not be appearing. I have no idea where this is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend the header `Content-Type: image/jpeg` before sending the contents of the image.

The browser can so interpret the file contents as jpeg and display it correctly.

With PHP: `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`